# What function is asymptotically eqyivalent to $\sum_{k \geq 0}k!/N^k$?

Tags: algorithms, asymptotics, approximation, factorial

I am working on this problem to find a function $f(N)$ s.t.

$$
f(N) \sim \sum_{k \geq 0}\frac{k!}{N^k}
$$

where $\sim$ means that given functions $f$ and $g$, we have $f \sim g \implies f = O(g) \text{ and } f=\Omega(g)$.

For instance, given the right hand side of the equation above, on input $N$ we have the following (it's a divergent series)

$$
f(N) \sim 1 + \frac{1}{N} + \frac{1}{2N^2} + \frac{1}{6N^3} + O\bigg(\frac{1}{N^4}\bigg)
$$

The closest function I can think of are the binomials where:

$$
(N \text{ choose } r) \sim \frac{N^r}{r!}
$$

But it doesnt really equal the first equation above. Any help?

Comment: Is the $k!$ in the denominator or the numerator?

Comment: In the numerator

Comment: $\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{k!}{N^k}=\infty$ for all $N \in \{1, 2, 3, ...\}$. So, you are trying to find a function that is asymptotically similar to infinity.  The first few terms you have written out suggest that $k!$ should be in the denominator (as Asvin comments), they are inconsistent with your formula.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following Robert Israel's suggestion.

Since
$(f(x)/x)' = - f(x)/x + 1/x
$,
if we let
$g(x) = f(x)/x$
then
$g'+g = 1/x$,
$e^x(g'+g) = e^x/x$,
$(e^xg)' = e^x/x$,
$e^xg = \int e^x/x$,
$f(x)/x
=g
=e^{-x}\int(e^t dt)/t
$
so
$f(x)
=xe^{-x}\int(e^t dt)/t
$.

Answer (score 2):

Hint: formally, your divergent series satisfies the differential equation
$$ (f(x)/x)' = - f(x)/x + 1/x$$

Comment: This is the first I have heard that $\infty$ satisfies a differential equation.